# Stop tkinter frame from being pushed off screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

I have a `tk` window with 3 frames, a left side that works like a tree structure with labels that will be added and removed with `.grid()` and `grid_remove()`, a right frame that will display information about these items, and a bottom frame that will hold buttons. If I expand too many items on the left frame(lframe) it pushes the bottom frame (bframe) out of view. I would rather the bottom frame stop when it gets to the edge of the window and the scrollbar for the lframe be used to view the items for lframe.

Here is a simple example of what im seeing. As you click the button more label widgets will be created and it will push the `bframe` out of view.

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(main)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
lframe = Frame(canvas)
lframe.grid(row=0, column=1)


sbar = Scrollbar(canvas)
sbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)
sbar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

rframe = Frame(main)
rframe.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

bframe = Frame(main)
bframe.grid(row=1, column=1)


cnt = 1
def addmore():
    global cnt

    test = Label(lframe, text='this \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe\nthis \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe\nthis \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe\nthis \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe\nthis \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe\n')
    test.grid(row=cnt, column=0)
    cnt += 1
    lframe.update()


llbl = Label(lframe, text='this \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe')
llbl.grid()

rlbl = Label(rframe, text='this is the RIGHT frame')
rlbl.grid()
btn = Button(rframe, text='click me', command=addmore)
btn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
blbl = Label(bframe, text='this is the BOTTOM frame', bg="yellow")
blbl.grid(row=0)


main.mainloop()
```

Question 1:
 How can I stop the bframe from pushing off the screen? I want it to stop when it gets to the bottom of `main` and the labels in `lframe` start pushing out of view behind `bframe`. Then the user would use the scrollbar to view the other items in `lframe`.

Question 2:
 I wont know if my scrollbar is configured correctly until I can get the lframe to stop pushing off the screen. If its not setup right, what do I need to change?

Comment: The way to fix the issue with resizing is probably using column and row weights here. with `rowconfigure()` and `columnconfigure()`. I have fixed the resizing on my end but for some reason I am not able to get the scrollbar thing to work. I will keep messing with it until I figure out why this is.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech based on the documentation the weight just handles how fast it grows. Adding it to the example above didn't change anything.

Comment: It does but if you add a zero weight to say the last row for the bottom frame and then add a weight of 1 to the top row for the top frame in the main window then the bottom frame will never be pushed out.

Comment: I will provide an example once I have all the bugs worked out on my end. Still trying to figure out why the scrollbar is not working as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you would set this scrolling canvas up with weights in the main frame. Its not perfect but it should be enough to help.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, width = 50, height = 100)
        self.lframe = tk.Frame(self.canvas, width=10)
        self.sbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.sbar.set)

        self.sbar.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsw")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.canvas.create_window((2,2), window=self.lframe, anchor="ne", 
                                  tags="self.lframe")

        self.lframe.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.rframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.rframe.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="n")

        self.bframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.bframe.grid(row=1, column=2)

        llbl = tk.Label(self.lframe, text='this \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe')
        llbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        rlbl = tk.Label(self.rframe, text='this is the RIGHT frame')
        rlbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        btn = tk.Button(self.rframe, text='click me', command=self.addmore)
        btn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="n")
        blbl = tk.Label(self.bframe, text='this is the BOTTOM frame', bg="yellow")
        blbl.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "s")

        self.bframe.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.bframe.rowconfigure(2, weight = 0)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 0)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight = 0)

        self.cnt = 1

    def addmore(self):
        test = tk.Label(self.lframe, text='this \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe\nthis \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe\nthis \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe\nthis \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe\nthis \nis \nthe \nLEFT \nframe\n')
        test.grid(row=self.cnt, column=0)
        self.cnt += 1

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    Example().grid(row=0, column=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is almost what im after. The scrollbar works but the lframe isnt allowed to expand. This forces me to set a static size for lframe and that may not work on all monitors. I'll play with this a bit and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @sidnical: Do you need to auto expand and then stop at a specific point? You could set the max size of the frame.

Comment: The row and column configuration you have in the class doesn't seem to make a difference. I removed the configuration section  at the end of __init__ and it didn't seem to change anything about how the UI works. Does this example expand the lframe when you click the button to add more labels?

Comment: @sidnical Iframe does expand and the canvas resizes but the frame the canvas is in does not resize unless you resize the window.

Comment: odd, A direct copy and paste does not function the same for me. I,m using python 3.5.2. What version are you using?

Comment: @sidnical 3.6. I dont think the version is affection the situation. We might just be not on the same page here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150668/discussion-between-sidnical-and-sierra-mountain-tech).